# How can the entropy of quantum states increase after projective measurements?

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, information-theory, entropy

I'm reading Nielsen and chuang 11.3.3 Measurements and Entropy.
It says after measurement, one's entropy increases.
How is this possible? Shouldn't measurement decrease one's uncertainty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key feature that you've left out of the question is the requirement that the measurement is performed, but we **do not learn** the answer.

For example, imagine starting with a $|+\rangle$ state. You measure it in the $Z$ basis, so you get answers $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ with 50:50 probability. If you knew which result you'd got, then great, you have a pure state and 0 entropy. But if you don't know the result, your best description of the state is $\frac12|0\rangle\langle 0|+\frac12|1\rangle\langle 1|$ which obviously has 1 bit of entropy.

---

I might add that even if you do learn the measurement result, you are not guaranteed to have a lower entropy. For example, one of your projectors could project onto a maximally mixed subspace. Instead, it is only the average entropy that does not increase, which is perfectly compatible with some specific answers having higher entropy.

For example, let $$\rho=(1-x)|00\rangle\langle 00|+\frac{x}{2}|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes I.$$
$\rho$ has eigenvalues $1-x,x/2,x/2$, so you can easily evaluate its entropy. Now, measure the first qubit in the $Z$ basis. With probability $1-x$, I get the answer $|0\rangle$, the output state is a pure state, and hence has entropy 0. However, with probability $x$, we get the answer $|1\rangle$, and the state of the second qubit is $I/2$, which has entropy 1. The average entropy is $x$, which is less than the original entropy of $x+h(x)$, where $h(x)$ is the binary entropy.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a toy example on for instance 2 qubits for your last statement?